# Bash script to read EXIF, rename JPG files and check output if file exit -> create newfile-01.jpg

Tags: bash

**Update: 10.12.2014 - 
Fixed!!
Script finds all jpg,jpeg,JPG files in folder+all_subfolders and sets file modification timestamp=exif date/time.
+it also writes the size of image into the filename too. (neat to know pixel size of image by just looking at the filname)**

Original:
I been working on a script for long time, picking up info traces of info and code to use.
I have managed to make a script. Run it in a folder, and it will pick up all .jpg .JPG in current and subfolders and rename them to filename. i.e:  *2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320.jpg*

**Problem**
The photos may have been taken at the same time with fast shutter speed. For example:
2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320.jpg  (original filename P00002727.jpg)
2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320.jpg  (original filename P00002728.jpg)

The first file is written okay, and then the *second file overwrites the first one* :-/

**If someone could help**
I would like the script to have a "if file exist, the new filename should be renamed to having an increased number 01,02,03..etc.." at the end of the filename. Like this:

2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320.jpg
2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320_01.jpg   (added _01,02,03 etc..)

The script I'm using:

```
#!/bin/bash

#extensions="jpg,jpeg,png,gif,psd,bmp,crw,thm,tif,tiff"
fileTypes="jpg,jpeg,JPG"

#make regex to find files with extensions in $fileTypes
fileTypes=".*\.\(${fileTypes//,/\|}\)"

# loop through all the image files
find . -iregex "$fileTypes" -print0 | sort | while read -d "" s
#find . -iregex '.*\.\(jpg\|JPG\|jpeg\)$' -print0 | while read -d $'\0' s
#find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' s

#find . -type f -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | while read -r -d $'\0' s ;

#find . -iname "*.jpg" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' s ;


#for s in $(find . -iname *.jpg -print0 | while read -d $'\0' s);
do
echo "------------  Start --------------------------"

echo ""
let counting=counting+1
echo "Number of files: $counting"

## skip files that already contain _XX increment
#ffn="${s##*/}"                                        # full filename w/o path
#fn="${ffn%.*}"                                        # split filename from ext
#if [ "${fn: -3:1}" = '_' ]; then                      # have we added '_XX' before ?
#    continue                                          # skip to next file 's'
#fi

header=`jhead "$s"`                                     # header holds jhead info about
justFileName=`basename "$s" | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`
dateTime=`echo "$header" | grep "Date/Time"`            # dateTime fetches Date Time line
fileDate=`echo "$header" | grep "File date"`

path="`pwd "$s"/ `"
file="`echo "$s" | sed 's/^.//'`"    # . = 1. first chars is removed in front
pathwithfile="`echo $path$file`"     # does not lookup directory with spaces
pathwithspaces="$PWD$file"           # does lookup direcotyr with spaces!
justPath=`dirname "$pathwithfile"`

exifdateTime=`echo $dateTime | awk -F ":" '{print $2"_"$3"_"$4"_"$5"_"$6}' | awk -F " " '{print $1"_"$2}'`

dateFileTime=`echo $fileDate | awk -F "_" '{print $1"_"$2"_"$3"_"$4"_"$5"_"$6}' | awk -F ":" '{print $2"_"$3"_"$4"_"$5"_"$6}'`
#| cut -c 16-34`
#datefileName=`echo $justFileName | cut -c 1-19`



FULLPATH="$pathwithspaces"
# remove all the prefix until "/" character
FILENAME=${FULLPATH##*/}
# remove all the prefix unitl "." character
FILEEXTENSION=${FILENAME##*.}
# remove a suffix, in our cas, the filename, this will return the name of the directory that contains this file
BASEDIRECTORY=${FULLPATH%$FILENAME}

#echo "FULLPATH = $FULLPATH"
#echo "FILENAME = $FILENAME"
#echo "FILEEXTENTION = $FILEEXTENSION"
#echo "BASEDIRECTORY = $BASEDIRECTORY"


#echo "dateTime: $dateTime"
#echo "exifdateTime: $exifdateTime"
#echo "fileDate: $fileDate"
#echo "dateFileTime: $dateFileTime"
#echo "pathwithfile: $pathwithfile"
#echo "pathwithspaces: $pathwithspaces"



stripedfilename=`echo $FILENAME | cut -c 1-19`

if [ $exifdateTime = $stripedfilename ]; then
echo "File \"$s\" already exists with exifdateTime: $stripedfilename"
echo "..skip to next file"
echo "--- End ---"

continue
        stripedfiledate=$fileDate | cut -c 1-19
        if [ $stripedfiledate = $stripedfilename ] ; then
        echo "File \"$s\" already exists with fileDate: $stripedfiledate"
        echo "..skip to next file"
        echo "--- End ---"
        continue
        fi
fi

#echo "break"
#break




#if [ -z "$dateTime" ] || [[ $dateTime == "Date/Time    : 0000:00:00 00:00:00" ]];
if [ "$dateTime" = "Date/Time    : 0000:00:00 00:00:00" ]
then

        if [ -z "$fileDate" ]
        then
                # If Date/Time=0000:00:00 check File date
                dateTime=`echo "$header" | grep "File date"`
#               echo "Date/Time(ny): $fileDate"

                # Set timestamp from exif
#               echo "File date(ny): $exifdateTime"
                jheadrun=`jhead -autorot -exonly -ft -norot "$FULLPATH"`

        else
                # Set exif = modified timestamp.
                jheadrun=`jhead -dsft "$FULLPATH"`

#echo "..fixed Date/Time:   0000..."
#echo "break 1"
#break

        fi



# Set new dateTime
header=`jhead "$s"`                                     # header holds jhead info about
dateTime=`echo "$header" | grep "Date/Time"`
#justFileName=`basename "$s" | sed 's/\(.*\)\..*/\1/'`
exifdateTime=`echo $dateTime |  awk -F ":" '{print $2"_"$3"_"$4"_"$5"_"$6}' | awk -F " " '{print $1"_"$2}'`


fi


# if -z variable is zero
# if -n variable is none-zero

if [ "$fileDate" = "" ] ;
then
#echo "break 2"
#break

#echo "breake 2 - True"
        # Set exif = modified timestamp.
        jheadrun=`jhead -dsft "$FULLPATH"`
#       echo "jhead -dsft $jheadrun"
else
#echo "break 2 - False"
        # Set Date/Time from File-modification timestamp
#        echo "Date/Time(ny): $exifdateTime"
        jheadrun=`jhead -autorot -exonly -ft -norot "$FULLPATH"`
#       echo "`jhead -autorot -exonly -ft -norot \"$FULLPATH\"`"

fi




#
# check file do have Modification date
# if yes
# set Date/Time = modification date
#
if [ "$dateTime" = "" ] ;
then
#echo "break 3"
#break

echo "breake 3 - True"
        # Set exif = modified timestamp.
        jheadrun=`jhead -mkexif -dsft "$FULLPATH"`
        echo "jhead -mkexif -dsft $jheadrun"
fi



if [ "$exifdateTime" != "$dateFileTime" ]
then

#echo "break 4"
#break



# echo $s
 x=`jhead "$s" | \
 awk 'BEGIN { cmt=""; }
#/File name/      { n=$4; gsub(".jpg","",n);}
/Camera model/   { c=$4$5$6;}
/Exposure time:/ { e=$3;
                   if (e==int(e)) e=int(e);
                   if (e<1) {e=int(0.5+1/e); e="1T" e "s";} else { e=e "s"; }
                 }
/ISO equiv./     { iso="ISO" $4; }
/Focal length/   { f="f" $4; }
/Date.Time /     { d=$3 "_" $4; gsub(":","_",d); }
/Resolution /    { size=$3$4$5$6; }
/Aperture /      { ap=$3; gsub("f/","F",ap); }
/Comment  /      { cmt=$3 "_"; }
END { print d "_" c "_" size "_" ap "_" f "_" e "_" iso ".jpg"; }'`


commentcheck=`echo "$header" | grep Comment | awk -F ":" '{print $2}'`


if [ "$commentcheck" != " Original_filename" ]
then
#echo "break 5"

comment="Original_filename: $FILENAME"
commentcommand="jhead -cl \"$comment\""


echo "..no comment in file, adding; $comment  <-- adding comment"

#echo "commment: $comment"
#echo "commentcheck: $commentcheck      <-- if this is blank file does not have comment"
#echo "commentcommand: $commentcommand"

addcomment="$commentcommand \"$pathwithfile\""
#addcomment=("jhead -cl $comment $pathwithfile")

#echo "addcomment: $addcomment"

eval $addcomment  # Run variable in terminal

else
continue

fi

#echo "break 6"
#break

########



PADDING=2
NEWFILE="$BASEDIRECTORY$x"

if [[ -f $NEWFILE ]]; then
    BASE=`echo $x | sed "s/\.jpg/_/"`
#echo $BASE
    LAST=`ls -1 "$BASEDIRECTORY" | grep $BASE | sort -r | head -1`
#echo $LAST
    LASTNUM=`echo ${LAST:${#x}-3:$PADDING} | sed "s/^0*//"`
#echo $LASTNUM
    let LASTNUM=LASTNUM+1
#echo $LASTNUM
    FINAL=$BASE$(printf "%0"$PADDING"d.jpg" ${LASTNUM})
#echo $FINAL
    NEWFILE=$BASEDIRECTORY$FINAL
fi


mv "$s" "$NEWFILE"
#NODUPLICATE="jhead -n%f-%02i \"$pathwithspaces\" \"$NEWFILE\""
#echo "mv \"$pathwithspaces\" \"$NEWFILE\""

echo "New filename: $NEWFILE"



#echo "---"
#header=`jhead "$NEWFILE"`
#echo "$header"
#echo "---"

#echo "break 6"
#break

#echo "$s"

fi # END OF if [ "$exifdateTime" != "$datefileName" ]

unset x
#echo "$x"

#echo "Sleeping 1/100 of a second"
sleep 0.01
#sleep 0.05
#sleep 3

echo "End..------------------------------------------------"
echo ""
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before:

```
mv "$s" "$NEWFILE"
```

use something like:

```
PADDING=2
echo "New filename: "
NEWFILE="$BASEDIRECTORY$x"
if [[ -f $NEWFILE ]]; then
    BASE=`echo $x | sed "s/\.jpg/_/"`    
    LAST=`ls -1 $BASEDIRECTORY | grep $BASE | sort -r | head -1`
    LASTNUM=`echo ${LAST:${#x}-3:$PADDING} | sed "s/^0*//"` 
    let LASTNUM=LASTNUM+1
    FINAL=$BASE$(printf "%0"$PADDING"d.jpg" ${LASTNUM})
    NEWFILE=$BASEDIRECTORY$FINAL
fi
```

You can of'course use `counter` of your script to handle sequential numbers, but this version won't recount on re-run (safer I think).

Comment: Thank you very much for commenting and helping!
I ran the script and works very good! But when rerunning the script  it creates several more _01 files.. is there a way to "not check" the files that already have been altered ? (maybe earlier in the script)

Comment: reruning it the same set of files in the same BASEDIRECTORY **should** create everytime new file.

Comment: I'm very greatfull for the answer I've got already. Don't get me wrong! :)
I ran the script once, and produces 5 - _01 files. Correct.
Then reran the script and it created 345 - _01 files. :-/
I'm guessing that I need something in my script earlier on -to check if the files has been created and skip to next file. How do I skip in bash scripts (i.e. goto) ?

Comment: Let's say you have one file `some.jpg` the script reads exif and changes its name to `123_iso_f20.jpg` (for example). Now if you rerun  in the same directory with the same files, and the same target dir, the script will again read some'jpg's exif, but now it won't save to `123_iso_f20.jpg` (because it was created at the first run and it should not replace existing one) it will create `123_iso_f20_01.jpg` and so on...  So in your case first created only needed seq, next run (the same files) created for all.

Comment: I need to work on this. I see that I have to skip all the files that have been created already.. by checking if the file have the exif info in the filename, goto next.

Comment: I may have found a way with your script, but I needed to add some if-check-file routine to skip files that already existed..

Answer (score 1):

Where you create `NEWFILE="$BASEDIRECTORY$x"` you want something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "New filename: "
NEWFILE="$BASEDIRECTORY$x"
ntmp="$NEWFILE"
while [ -e "$ntmp" ]; do                                  # while the file "$ntmp" exist...
    ffn="${ntmp##*/}"                                     # full filename w/o path
    fn="${ffn%.*}"                                        # split filename from ext
    ext="${ntmp#*${fn}.}"                                 # get the ext
    if [ "${fn: -3:1}" = '_' ]; then                      # does filename have '_XX' ?
        if [[ "${fn: -2}" =~ [^0-9] ]]; then              # if 'XX' isn't 2 digits [0-9]
            ntmp="${fn}_01.${ext}"                        # it's not ours, just add _01, and
            continue                                      # continue
        fi
        count=$((${fn: -2}+1))                            # if 2-digits, get the XX and add +1
        if [ "$count" -lt 10 ]; then
            ntmp="${fn:0:$((${#fn}-3))}_0${count}.${ext}" # if 1-digit, replace w/ '_0${count}'
        else
            ntmp="${fn:0:$((${#fn}-3))}_${count}.${ext}"  # if 2-digit, replace w/ '_${count}'
        fi
    else                                                  # if first dup, just add '_01'
        ntmp="${fn}_01.${ext}"
    fi
done

mv "$s" "$ntmp"
```

**repetive filenames:**

```
$ ls -1 20*
2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320.jpg
2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320_01.jpg
2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320_02.jpg
```

**NOTE:** When using **reverse string indexes** (e.g. `${fn: -2}`) you **MUST** include a space before the `-` sign (or place the index in parentheses (e.g. `${fn:(-2)}`).

When working in `bash` try to utilize the tools bash provides and get away from using external applications and pipes (which each spawn a separate process and subshell of their own) such as (`grep`, `awk`, `cut`, and '|'). There is virtually nothing bash can't do as far as string/line parsing goes utilizing its own **parameter expansion / substring extraction / substring substitution** and **string indexes**. There is nothing wrong with calling external apps from within a script, just don't use them to replace what bash already does for you.

Since you are working with `bash` and `jhead`, you may be interested in some of the ideas in this [**Iphone Image Rename w/jhead**](http://www.3111skyline.com/dl/dev/stack/bash/iphrename.sh) script. Which takes a slightly different approach to parsing `jhead` image output and has a few handy functions you may make use of.

---

Per our discussion in the comments, if you are feeding all filenames (including those previously incremented with _XX increments) back through the script, you will want to skip processing those files again.

To omit files already incremented from the main loop, you will need something like the following at the beginning of the `find | while` loop:

```
# loop through all the image files
find . -iregex "$fileTypes" -print0 | while read -d "" s
do

## skip files that already contain _XX increment
ffn="${s##*/}"                                   # full filename w/o path
fn="${ffn%.*}"                                   # split filename from ext
if [ "${fn: -3:1}" = '_' ]; then                 # does the file have '_XX' suffix
    if [[ "${fn: -2}" =~ [0-9][0-9] ]]; then     # if 2 digits, assume prior increment
        continue                                 # skip to next file 's'
    fi
fi
```

---

OK. To get to the bottom of this, and to help us to communicate more effectively, I have created a testcase script. The problem I was having is I did not have files from your camera or your files to know what all I was dealing with. This left me trying to handle all cases as broadly as possible (which should be done regardless). But the following will allow testing **input files** against what the **output filename** would be. I have left your original script contents (in comments) to show the context of where the tests are taking place and I have commented and replaced parts necessary for the testcase. Here is the script and testcases verified:

```
#!/bin/bash

# fileTypes="jpg,jpeg"

#make regex to find files with extensions in $fileTypes
# fileTypes=".*\.\(${fileTypes//,/\|}\)"

# loop through all the image files
# find . -iregex "$fileTypes" -print0 | while read -d "" s
for s in "$@"
do

## skip files that already contain _XX increment
    ffn="${s##*/}"                                   # full filename w/o path
    fn="${ffn%.*}"                                   # split filename from ext
    if [ "${fn: -3:1}" = '_' ]; then                 # does the file have '_XX' suffix
        if [[ "${fn: -2}" =~ [0-9][0-9] ]]; then     # if 2 digits, assume prior increment
            continue                                 # skip to next file 's'
            echo "XX is digits, skipping"
        fi
    fi

    ## rest of your script here...

    #NEWFILE="$BASEDIRECTORY$x"
    NEWFILE="$s"
    ntmp="$NEWFILE"
    while [ -e "$ntmp" ]; do                                  # while the file "$ntmp" exist...
        ffn="${ntmp##*/}"                                     # full filename w/o path
        fn="${ffn%.*}"                                        # split filename from ext
        ext="${ntmp#*${fn}.}"                                 # get the ext
        if [ "${fn: -3:1}" = '_' ]; then                      # does filename have '_XX' ?
            if [[ "${fn: -2}" =~ [^0-9] ]]; then              # if 'XX' isn't 2 digits [0-9]
                ntmp="${fn}_01.${ext}"                        # it's not ours, just add _01, and
                continue                                      # continue
            fi
            count=$((${fn: -2}+1))                            # if 2-digits, get the XX and add +1
            if [ "$count" -lt 10 ]; then
                ntmp="${fn:0:$((${#fn}-3))}_0${count}.${ext}" # if 1-digit, replace w/ '_0${count}'
            else
                ntmp="${fn:0:$((${#fn}-3))}_${count}.${ext}"  # if 2-digit, replace w/ '_${count}'
            fi
        else                                                  # if first dup, just add '_01'
            ntmp="${fn}_01.${ext}"
        fi
    done

# mv "$s" "$ntmp"

if [ "$s" = "$ntmp" ]; then
    printf "\n  no change   : %s\n\n" "$s"
else
    printf "\n  file exists : %s\n  new fname   : %s\n\n" "$s" "$ntmp"
fi

done

exit 0
```

**existing files:**

```
$ ls -1  20*
2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320.jpg
2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320_01.jpg
2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320_02.jpg
2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320_AB.jpg
```

**file renaming:**

```
$ bash newfn.sh \
2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320.jpg \
2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320_AB.jpg \
2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320_AC.jpg

  file exists : 2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320.jpg
  new fname   : 2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320_03.jpg


  file exists : 2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320_AB.jpg
  new fname   : 2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320_AB_01.jpg


  no change   : 2014_10_19_12_24_05_DSC-RX100_F5.6_f37.1mm_1T250s_ISO320_AC.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you, very good!
If I rerun the script again, it creates more _01 and _02 files than I already had from first execution.
Is there a way of skipping these files that have been touched ?

Comment: Well, that does make a difference if you are writing the same set of files over-and-over again. The routine should only create a _XX +1 file if you try to write to a file that already exists. **Are you using all files, including the _XX files as input filenames?** Such that your code passes not only the original file, but the _XX files to `NEWFILE="$BASEDIRECTORY$x"`?? If so, yes, you can check/filter/discard attempts to resave files that already have _XX. I'll add an update to the answer - it will be after lunch.

Comment: Number of files counted: 1021. Then I get an error:: 
./dcamera.sh: line 255: 08: value too great for base (error token is "08")
What does this error mean ? (rerun the script and it counts exactly same number of files, 1021)

Comment: This means something is being interpreted as a numeric base that is **out of limits**, I believe. (did you preserve the space before the `-`) **(it usually means you have a string in something you expect to be a number)** Let's do a bit of debugging. Under `#!/bin/bash` add the line `set -x`. This will cause the variable values for each line to be printed to `stdout` while the code is running. Run the program (you will get **LOTS** of output (you can `tee` or `redirect` it to a file if you like) Then look at values around the error. It should be clear. (the added code shouldn't do it)

Comment: Hi, the code does seem to work, but generate _01 and _02 files on all the files. I must be doing something wrong here..
What I'm looking for is base filename:
2014_10_19_12_42_15_DSC-RX100_F4.0_f10.4mm_1T250s_ISO320.jpg
If basename is taken, create next;
2014_10_19_12_42_15_DSC-RX100_F4.0_f10.4mm_1T250s_ISO320_01.jpg
If this _01 is taken, create next;
2014_10_19_12_42_15_DSC-RX100_F4.0_f10.4mm_1T250s_ISO320_02.jpg
etc..

Comment: It should be doing that, let me look at it again. I may have been sleeping :)

Comment: I added a split of the path from the full-filename, and I added a test that `XX` in `_XX` were digits. If for some reason you had a filename ending in `_AB` where `AB` were letters, that could cause problems. Give it another go and well take it up from there.

Comment: Ah, sorry for taking up your time like this :)
First run; That save the _01.jpg files to root folder (where I run the script from)
Second run; created a bunch of _01.jpg files. (now all files are moved from their folder to root folder)
I'm belive maybe it would be better to check if the files have got filename i.e. 2014_10_19_12_42_15_   then we know that the files have been altered and can skip to the next file.
I have modified the original script with both your code, and another script with the other code.. I can post the result, but that closed the case, right?

Comment: I added a bit more. We needed to realize if not 2-digits, `_AB` were part of the original filename and to just add `_01`. I'll have a bit more time this evening to look at it further. You can just edit this question add the new code to the end (the way I'm doing with the answer). That keeps it all together. We will also need to add similar checks at the beginning to distinguish between `_XX` and `_AB`.

Comment: It was my fault I had used `[` with the `=~` operator (which won't work, because `=~` is only allowed with `[[`. That is where the binary error came from. I have been getting away from using `[[` for portability purposes, but it is needed where it is needed :)

Comment: Take a look at the `testcase` script posted and run it against your files to verify the tests. You will need to comment my `for s in "$@"` and uncomment your original `iregex` and `while` loop to run on your existing files all at once, or you can use as is with `find blah -exec testcase.sh '{}' \;` to feed it multiple file. I set it up to handle files provided on the command line.

Comment: I will merge my code into yours and will see if I get the right results. I tried some but failed. Will try more tomorrow.

Comment: I still can't this to work correcly. It only creates alot of _01 files. Sorry..

I have posted the script that works, but I had to use the other solution, solely because I do understand the use of commands better than bash operators.. (but I'm learning your way of doing by testing the way you have written the script too!)
If you check my new script, you see what I'm trying to achieve.. (maybe I was abit unclear about what I needed, sorry for that..)

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look. There must be something odd about the way the `awk` statement is forming `$x`, because the check/increment I posted only creates an `_01` increment **1.** if the file exists and **(a)** has no `_XX` suffix, or **(b)** has an `_AB` suffix. For processing, it only skips files that already have a `_XX` suffix. I'll test the awk logic on files I have and let you know.

Comment: Super! Looking forward to it. The easier and better script the better.. I'm planning on running this on my picture base with 140.000 images..and counting.. takes with different cameras up through the years :-)

Comment: Now that the script works. 
Checking folder, and renaming the files to a new name...is great.

But would like to port this script from copying from A->B instead.

Comment: I don't quite understand which file you are wanting to copy A->B? In the original, we took a new set of filenames and compared them against existing files. If any of the new filenames conflict with one that already exists, that filename is modified by adding a suffix until it no longer conflicts. Explain a bit more what you mean by `copying from A->B instead`? Are we just copying the new file over the existing?

Answer (score 0):

`man mv(1)` has all the info you need. Here it is an example of using the numeric backup option

```
% touch aaa1 aaa2 aaa3 aaa4
% for fn in {1..4} ; do mv --backup=t aaa$fn bbb1 ; done
% ls bbb*
bbb1  bbb1.~1~  bbb1.~2~  bbb1.~3~
%
```

#### Addendum

Using `mv --backup=t ...` has a small defect, it uses the plain name for the last moved file, in my example above `aaa1 -> bbb1.~1~`, `aaa2 -> bbb1.~2~`, `aaa3 -> bbb1.~3~` and (but) `aaa4 -> bbb1`.

This is perfectly logical from `mv` POV and possibly less desirable for the OP.

The script below moves the unnumbered file in its logical position
(and works for any number of files that need renaming at the end of the day)

```
% for x in $(sed s/....\$// <(printf %s\\n *.\~?\~) | uniq) ; do
>   if [ -f $x ] ; then
>     last=$(ls ${x}*~ |tail -1 | sed -r 's/(.*)~([0-9]+)~$/\2/')
>     mv $x $x.'~'$(($last+1))'~'
    fi
> done
% ls bbb1*
bbb1.~1~  bbb1.~2~  bbb1.~3~  bbb1.~4~
%
```

The photos that were taken in a very short sequence are now all numbered from 1 to N