# Bash script to set folder date to file-date-within folder

Tags: bash

I see I've got some minus points,..so I'll try to address this better:

I have a linux server. (centos 6.5)

```
This stores all images in /mnt/usb1/images/

This folder also have several subfolders.
drwxrwxr-x     2  1033 users     4096 Jan 25  2009   /mnt/usb1/images/2014_sept_NewYork 
drwxrwxr-x     2  1033 users     4096 Jan 25  2009   /mnt/usb1/images/2014_sept_Chicago
..

Would be nice to set the folder date - to same date as image inside folder.
-rwxrw-r--    1 1033 users 1753062 Mar  4  2007 IMG_0301.jpg
-rwxrw-r--    1 1033 users 1752525 Mar  4  2007 IMG_0302.jpg

Result: 
drwxrwxr-x     2  1033 users     4096 Mar 4  2007   /mnt/usb1/images/2014_sept_NewYork 
drwxrwxr-x     2  1033 users     4096 Mar 4  2007   /mnt/usb1/images/2014_sept_Chicago
```

---

My script works, but would be nice with some help/comments and improvements:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "" # Space at start
echo "###############################################"
echo "#                                             #"
echo "# Setting folders to file modifications date  #"
echo "#                                             #"
echo "###############################################"

echo "--- `date` ---" >> SetFileDate.txt

while read file
do
  touch -t $(date -r "$file" +%Y%m%d%H%M) "$(dirname "$file")"

# echo date - folder/filename
  echo "`date -r \"$file\"+%Y%m%d%H%M` - \"$dirname $file\"" >> SetFileDate.txt

done < <(find . \( -iname \*.JPG -o -iname \*.jpg -o -iname \*.TIF -o -iname \*.avi -o -iname \*.mkv \))

echo "" >> SetFileDate.txt
```

---

Why I want this ?
Its because at earlier point, i copied an moved file and forgot to retain permissions.. and this screwed up the folder modified time.

---

..my other idea is finished (thanks to the people that contribute here on stackoverflow), it is about setting the filenames to all files inside local and subfolders.
Check out script here: [Bash script to read EXIF, rename JPG files and check output if file exit -> create newfile-01.jpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26963377/bash-script-to-read-exif-rename-jpg-files-and-check-output-if-file-exit-crea)

Comment: do you mean latest date of an image inside the folder?

Comment: Yes, latest date of an image inside folder would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enter into te folder, and execute:

```
touch . -t $(printf "%.2i %.2i %.2i %.2i %.2i.%.2i" \
           $(echo $(ls -1t --full-time | sed -n "2p" | \
             sed -e 's/\(\s\|:\|-\|\.\)\+/\n/g' | \
             sed -n "9,14p"))| sed "s/\s\+//g")
```

This should get last time of the file inside the folder, and set the time of the folder according it.